# SonarQube: Is the Collation for the Database or the Instance?

Tags: sql-server, sonarqube, collation, sonarqube-ops

According to the SonarQube documentation "Installing the Server" (https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/sonar/installing+the+server), for a Microsoft SQL Server host, "collation MUST be case-sensitive (CS) and accent-sensitive (AS)."

The documentation is not clear if the collation must be set:

- for the SQL Server instance, or
- the database

If the collation for the SQL Server (and specifically for tempdb) is "accent insensitive" and the database collation is "accent sensitive", does SonarQube accommodate this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

> If the collation for the SQL Server (and specifically for tempdb) is "accent insensitive" and the database collation is "accent sensitive", does SonarQube accommodate this configuration?

Since the documentation is ambiguous (they might not use SQL Server enough to know the different levels where Collation can be set), the only two ways to get the answer here are:

1. Contact their community: https://www.sonarqube.org/community/feedback/. This is the best choice.
2. Install it on an Instance that has an accent insensitive default Collation and test it out. No reason not to try this.

Whether or not SonarQube handles this properly depends on how it was coded. They could be JOINing on string columns in temporary tables and any difference in Collation between the Database and Instance *could* potentially cause an error, but only if they are not specifically declaring the Collation when creating the temp tables.

Also, it is possible that their app needs the accent sensitivity because they have some variables names and/or cursor names and/or (less likely) `GOTO` label names that might equate under accent insensitivity that should otherwise be seen as different. Instance-level Collation controls these areas and would hence affect the name resolution of those items. Of course, this would be easy to test for since declaring two variables that are considered different names under accent sensitivity will cause a parse error if close enough to be considered the same under accent insensitivity. Still, contact their community.